# Find the points of perpendicularity for all normal lines to the parabola $y = \frac{1}{16}x^2$, that pass through the point $(3,15)$

Tags: calculus

I'm reading the book that presented following problem

> Find the points of perpendicularity for all normal lines to the
>   parabola $f(x) = \frac{1}{16}x^2$, that pass through the point $(3,15)$.

I have one question regarding author's solution to the problem

Screenshot of one part of the solution

[image]

Note the sentence:

> The derivative is $\frac{1}{8}x$ or $\frac{x}{8}$ and its opposite reciprocal is thus $-\frac{8}{x}$

Well, is it?

I'd thought that to find opposite reciprocal, we need to flip over the constant, not the variable. In other words:

If we have some line $y_{1} = ax + b$, then perpendicular line to it will be:
$$y_{2} = -\frac{1}{a}x + b$$

Thus considering our function $f(x) = \frac{1}{16}x^2$:
$$\text{Slope of tangent line at point } (x,f(x)) = \frac{1}{8}x$$
$$\text{Slope of the line perpendicular to the tangent line at point} (x,f(x)) = -8x$$

So which one is it?

Comment: You want to flip *the slope*. In your example, the slope is $a$, in the author's text, the slope is $\frac{x}{8}$.

Comment: @G.Chiusole So if we have line of the form $y = mx + b$, then the slope is $mx$, but not just $m$?

Comment: @Nelver did you skip lessons ?

Comment: No, the slope (meaning the value of the first derivative) is $m$. In the case of the author, $x$ is not meant as the variable in a linear equation, but as a variable giving the fixed slope. Example: Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$. Then the slope at a given point $x$ is $2x$ and thus the perpendicular has slope $-\frac{1}{2x}$. However, for the function $f(x) = 3x + 4$, the slope at any given $x$ is $3$. And thus the perpendicular has slope $-\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: @G.Chiusole. I'm sorry, I got confused. Now it's clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the slope a line is $m$, then the slope of line perpendicular to it is the opposite reciprocal of $m$: $$-\dfrac{1}{m}$$

If the slope of a line is $\dfrac{a}{8}$, then the slope of line perpendicular to it is the opposite reciprocal of $\dfrac{a}{8}$:
$$-\dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{a}{8}\right)} $$

Replace $a$ by $x$

Answer (score 1):

One way to check for perpendicularity is to use the fact that $\text{slope} \cdot \text{slope of perpendicular} = -1$.

However, in your working $\frac{1}{8}x \cdot -8x = -x^2 \ne -1$. ganeshie8's answer tells you how to find the correct slope of the perpendicular.